# FCM does not send message to IOS app when in background

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fcm

I am using [this](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) FCM library to understand how push notifications work. Running the example project, everything works well but only if the app is in the foreground. When the app goes to the background, messages are not delivered and even the breakpoints are not hit. What might I be doing wrong because I need the notifications in the background and even when the app is killed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue resolved it by going to Xcode->Capabilities->Background Modes

Toggle it on and check Background fetch and Remote Notifications respectively.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: I followed this tutorial [here](https://school.shoutem.com/lectures/react-native-chat-app-serverless-firebase-push-notifications/). Hope it helps you out